# Dynamically added control and buttons postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I have a problem with my GridView.
Let's say that I create a GridView with 4 columns

> |NAME|LASTNAME|OWNER|ADMINISTRATOR|

Owner and Administrator are columns that can contain a checkbox.
Second step: I fill the grid in some way.
Third step: I add dynamically the check box on the owner and admin columns, depending on some strange method.
Four step: When I click the Button below the gridview, the click event will read how many checkbox are checked and pass that number to another method.

This last step is quite difficult because all the checkboxes disappear, due to the postback of the button.
I looking for a method to save the checkboxes from the postback.

Can I call a method after the click, and before the postback?
Can I avoid the postback of a button?

(PS: I prefer to not go for js solution)

Answer (score 0):

If you place the method call to dynamically add the check boxes in Page_Init they will not be removed on postback

Comment: The grid is filled with a button event, if the user do not click a button the grid stay empty.

Comment: Can you do it in a way in which you do not dynamically add the check boxes? So there's always the check boxes and you just make them hidden? Or always populate the grid and just show the grid on the button press

Comment: The checkbox are added with a specific ID based of the name and last name like: CHECKBOX_{ROWINDEX}_{NAME}_{LASTNAME}_{COL}

Comment: If you place the method to bind to the grid in Page_Init then the grid and it's data & grid must remain static throughout the life cycle otherwise things just get out of whack. If you data is dynamic and you're creating controls during binding; the grid and controls need to be rebound/reapplied on every postback. It sounds like you need to take note of when the button to load the grid was clicked so on postbacks you can re-populate the grid.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question why you need to have dynamically added CheckBox controls, when you can just set their state server-side in the RowDataBound event of the GridView. Here is a worked example of your requirment boiled down to the barest minimum to illustrate:

CheckboxGrid.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="CheckboxGrid.aspx.cs" Inherits="CheckboxGrid" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:GridView ID="gvResourceUsers" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDataBound="gvResourceUsers_OnRowDataBound">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Name" DataField="Name"/>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Surname" DataField="Surname"/>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Owner">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbxOwner" runat="server"/>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Administrator">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbxAdministrator" runat="server"/>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSubmit" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"/>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

CheckboxGrid.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class CheckboxGrid : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            //Get data and bind the grid
            gvResourceUsers.DataSource = GetData();
            gvResourceUsers.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void gvResourceUsers_OnRowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        //As each row is data-bound, set the checkbox state.
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            var resourceUser = e.Row.DataItem as ResourceUser;
            var cbxOwner = e.Row.FindControl("cbxOwner") as CheckBox;
            var cbxAdministrator = e.Row.FindControl("cbxAdministrator") as CheckBox;

            cbxOwner.Checked = resourceUser.Owner;
            cbxAdministrator.Checked = resourceUser.Administrator;
        }
    }

    protected void btnSubmit_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var resourceUsers = new List<ResourceUser>();

        //Iterate the gridview rows and populate the collection from the postback data.
        foreach (GridViewRow row in gvResourceUsers.Rows)
        {
            resourceUsers.Add(
                new ResourceUser
                {
                    Name = row.Cells[0].Text,
                    Surname = row.Cells[1].Text,
                    Owner = ((CheckBox)row.Cells[2].FindControl("cbxOwner")).Checked,
                    Administrator = ((CheckBox)row.Cells[3].FindControl("cbxAdministrator")).Checked
                });
        }
    }

    private IEnumerable<ResourceUser> GetData()
    {
        //We just create some data for demo purposes. Here you would normally populate the collection from your database.
        var resourceUsers = new List<ResourceUser>
            {
                new ResourceUser{Name = "Bob", Surname = "Taylor", Owner = true, Administrator = true },
                new ResourceUser{Name = "Ann",  Surname = "Carter", Owner = false, Administrator = true },
                new ResourceUser{Name = "Toni",  Surname = "Wong", Owner = false, Administrator = false}
            };

        return resourceUsers;
    }

    //A data view model to contain our view data for the grid
    private class ResourceUser
    {
        public String Name { get; set; }

        public String Surname { get; set; }

        public Boolean Owner { get; set; }

        public Boolean Administrator { get; set; }
    }
}
```